# Some players won't get teleported to spawn

Tags: bukkit

I am having this issue where when a player joins the game they sometimes won't get teleported to the spawnpoint, but if they relog it will work and the player will get teleported. Why is this occurring?

JoinEvent:

```
public class JoinEvent implements Listener{

private Main main;

public JoinEvent(Main main) {
    this.main = main;

}

@EventHandler
public void onJoin(PlayerJoinEvent e) {
    Player p = e.getPlayer();

    main.players.add(p);



    Location loc = (Location) main.locationConfig.get("main.spawns.Lobby");
    main.saveFile();

    e.getPlayer().teleport(loc);



    p.sendMessage(Main.prefix + "§6Welcome to Trouble in Mineville!");

    e.setJoinMessage(p.getDisplayName() + " §6has joined the server.");

    p.setHealth(20D);
    p.setFoodLevel(20);
    p.setFireTicks(0);
    p.setGameMode(GameMode.ADVENTURE);




    if(Roles.innocent.size() > Roles.traitor.size()) {
        Roles.traitor.add(p);
    } else {
        Roles.innocent.add(p);

    }




        }

        //if(Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers().size() >= 2 || Waiting.timeUntilStart > 60) {
        //Bukkit.broadcastMessage(Main.prefix + "§6There are now 2 players online!");
        //Bukkit.broadcastMessage(Main.prefix + "§6Timer has been shortened to 60 seconds.");
        //Waiting.timeUntilStart = 60;

        //}

@EventHandler
  public void chatEvent(AsyncPlayerChatEvent event) {
  Player p = event.getPlayer();
  {
    if(GameState.getCurrentGamestate() == GameState.WAITING) {
    event.setFormat("§e0 §8§l┃ §5Scout §9" + "%s §8» §f%s");
    }

    if(GameState.getCurrentGamestate() == GameState.STARTING || GameState.getCurrentGamestate() == GameState.INGAME || GameState.getCurrentGamestate() == GameState.RESTARTING) {
        event.setFormat("§8§l┃ §5Scout §9" + "%s §8» §f%s");
        }

    if(main.spectators.contains(p)) {
        event.setFormat("§8§l┃ §4DEAD §8┃ §5Scout §9" + "%s §8» §f%s");
    }

    }
}
   }
```

Comment: Delay a little bit the teleport, else another plugin might be interacting with it. Delay by 5 ticks, for example (1s = 20 ticks)

Comment: In addition to what @Kerooker said, you could also change the event's priority e.g) @EventHandler(priority = EventPriority.LOWEST)

Answer (score 0):

Another plugin is likely conflicting with yours.

Fighting for the position that players first log into is a REALLY common conflict.

A popular alternative, is to schedule your teleport slightly after the player logs in.

You also need to remember, that since Bukkit/Spigot/Forge/Sponge are built off of reverse engineered code, the events break without notice occasionally on updates. So you could be experiencing a bug with the server software you use.

If you really want to debug this, you can debug the server, and see what plugins are listening to the onJoin event, and what they are doing.

It's also a bad idea to block on the main thread. You should be loading stuff in the background, or when the server starts up the first time. It's remotely possible that it's this blocking/delay that could be the cause of your timing issues, but doubtful.

> they sometimes won't get teleported to the spawnpoint, but if they
>   relog it will work and the player will get teleported.

This is a big hint, that whichever plugin that does this, may be only doing it on first join.

Either first join of the server full stop (when player.dat is created) or first join since the server came online since the last restart.

**Troubleshooting**

Update your server software, see if the problem continues.

Update your plugins, see if the problem continues.

Remove all other plugins, see if you still experience the issue, if so contact the forums/issuetracker/chatroom of the server software you use, or debug it yourself.

Slowly introduce your plugins back, in a Binary Search Order if you want to be efficient. When the problem comes back, you have found the plugin causing it.

If after all of this, it still occurs, it may be a bug in your own plugin, or the server software.